# Uploading File to server through WebApi gives exception for files larger than 1mb

Tags: c#, file, cordova, asp.net-web-api, cordova-plugins

I am Uploading file to server through WebApi, it working fine for small files which are in KBs but for files in Mbs it is giving exception

**Exception :**

Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage was filled by the caller of HttpRequest.GetBufferedInputStream.

**I have tried increasing max request length in Web.config gut it is of no use**

```
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"/>


  <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- 50MB in bytes, default is 30000000 or approx. 28.6102 Mb-->
        <!--<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="300000000" />-->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="700000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

I am sending file from cordova app by using [FileTransfer Cordova plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/)

**Client side code:**

```
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

   var ft = new FileTransfer();
   ft.upload($scope.fileSource, encodeURI(serverUrl), win, fail, options);
```

**Server Side Code:**

```
     public class UserFileController : BaseApiController
        {
            public HttpResponseMessage Post()
            {  
                var request = HttpContext.Current.Request; 
                if(request.Files.Count>0)
                {
                    var fileName = String.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), "jpg");
                    SaveFile(request.Files[0], fileName); 
}
}
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: NO... I have compressed file and then sent